# Missing MySql driver when using PySide2 QtSql QSqlDatabase

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, centos7, pyside2

I'm porting some code from `PySide` to `PySide2` and I've noticed that I'm missing a couple of sql drivers.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySide.QtSql; import PySide2.QtSql
>>> PySide.QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()
['QSQLITE', 'QSQLITE3', 'QMYSQL3', 'QMYSQL', 'QODBC3', 'QODBC', 'QPSQL7', 'QPSQL']
>>> PySide2.QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()
['QSQLITE', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
```

As you can see I'm missing `QMYSQL` on `PySide2` (among others). I need that one for my application to work.

I've tried installing a couple of packages like `mysql` `mysql-connector-python` through `pip` but that didn't change anything. Then I tried changing `QTDIR` because I noticed it was pointing to `/usr/lib64/qt-3.3` instead of `/usr/lib64/qt5`. That didn't do anything either.

I also checked `/usr/lib64/qt4/plugins/sqldrivers` and `/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers` for `libqsqlmysql.so` and it's present in both folders.

I'm on CentOS 7 by the way. I'm trying to get the software on CentOS 7 and 8, though.

Pretty much all of the posts I've seen about it the drivers aren't missing but they can't be loaded.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, the plugin directory is not in "/usr/lib64/qt5/plugins" so it doesn't load the mysql plugin. The solution is to copy the plugin so the first thing is to know the PySide2 directory plugin by executing the following command:

```
$ python3 -c "from PySide2 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.PluginsPath))"
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins
```

<s>So you should copy the .so using the following command:</s>

```
$ cp /usr/lib64/qt5/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers
```

Even so the .so points to the Qt of the OS instead of the Qt of PySide2:

```
$ ldd  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
```

Output

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb974f000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007faa76f00000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007faa76895000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faa76679000)
libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007faa76179000)
# ...
```

for this you must change the rpath using patchelf:

```
$ yum install epel-release
$ yum install patchelf
$ patchelf --set-rpath \$ORIGIN/../../lib  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
```

again:

```
$ ldd  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
```

Output

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd013ad000)
libQt5Sql.so.5 => /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f6e1fb4c000)
libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f6e1f359000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6e1f13d000)
libmysqlclient.so.18 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18 (0x00007f6e1ec3d000)
# ...
```

Finally:

```
$ python3 -c "from PySide2 import QtSql; print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())"
```

Output:

```
['QSQLITE', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
```

It seems that there is no binary compatibility between the plugins so it must be compiled using the source code:

```
$ python3 -m pip install aqtinstall
$ python3 -m aqt install 5.15.0 linux desktop --outputdir qt
$ sudo yum -y install git
$ sudo yum -y install libxcb libxcb-devel xcb-util xcb-util-devel xcb-util-*-devel libX11-devel libXrender-devel libxkbcommon-devel libxkbcommon-x11-devel libXi-devel libdrm-devel libXcursor-devel libXcomposite-devel
$ sudo yum -y install centos-release-scl
$ sudo yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc*
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'
$ sudo yum -y install mysql-devel
$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
$ git clone -b 5.15.0 git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git
$ cd qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql
$ sed -i 's/QMAKE_USE += mysql/# QMAKE_USE += mysql/g' mysql.pro
$ echo "INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/mysql" >> mysql.pro
$ echo "QMAKE_LIBDIR += /usr/lib64/mysql" >> mysql.pro
$ echo "LIBS += -lmysqlclient" >> mysql.pro
$ ../../../../../qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake
$ make
$ sudo cp ../plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/PySide2/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers
```

Finally:

```
$ python3 -c "from PySide2 import QtSql; print(QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers())"
```

Output:

```
['QSQLITE', 'QMARIADB', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
```

Comment: This is massively helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: The versions are different though. When I try to use the driver I get `Cannot mit incompatible Qt library (5.9.7) with this library (5.15.0)` and the application crashes. Do I need to build my own `libqsqlmysql.so` from source?